# Sails.js how to use for loop in async.series([ ])?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I want to use async.series([]) in my Services and then return the result to Controller. However, it seems like the optional callback function with async.series doesn't wait until the tasks finish before returning to controller.

```js
/* In Services */
getFunction: function(userInput, callback) {
  var results = {};
  
  async.series([
    //1: This function get a list JSON dataset of id and other attributes
    function(callback) {
      //Call a function to call API by using the userInput, return function(error, JSONdataset1)
      //If error, return callback(error)
      //Else results = JSON.parse(dataset1);
       callback(null, JSON.stringify(results));
    },
    //2: This function get a JSON object by input the id result from above function
    //I am not sure I should use for loop here as well, can someone advise me please!
    function(callback) {
      for(var result in results) {
        //Call another function to call API by using the id in the returned results, return function(error, JSONdataset2)
        //If error, return callback(error)
        //Else
        var aName = JSON.parse(JSONdataset2);
        results[result].name = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aName.attribute));
      }
      callback(null, JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  ],
  //res = [JSON.stringify(results), JSON.stringify(results)] and result should return to Controller
  //The problem is the callback doesn't wait above functions finish before return.
  function(error, res) {
    if(error) { return callback(error, null); }
    else { return callback(null, res); }
  });
  
}
```

Comment: The call you are making inside this for-loop is **really slower than the loop iteration**. So, once loop is complete the callback gets called and returns to your controller. The loop won't wait until that function call finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the code I posted earlier, I used async.waterfall.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, I would use the [async.each()](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function, e.g.

```
async.each(results, function(result){
    var aName = JSON.parse(JSONdataset2);
    results[result].name = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(aName.attribute));
    callback();
}, function(err){
    if(err) callback(err,null);
    else callback(null, JSON.stringify(results));
})
```

This will ensure that each of the results is iterated over before the callback belonging to your series function is called.